# What are the minimum requirements for Sybase ASE 15.7?

Tags: sap-ase

This is a ridiculous question to ask, because it should be on their webpage under technical requirements, but I can't find it.

So does anyone know:

1. What versions of Windows are supported for this database?
2. RAM requirements
3. Anything else that would prevent it from working on a vanilla install of Windows (server or otherwise)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that information can be found in the ["Installation Guide Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7 for Windows"](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35888.1570/doc/html/jon1256241632272.html), under System Requirements.  From that documentation:
Windows Requirements
Windows X86 and X64 System Requirements Operating System Hardware Supported Protocols 
Windows 2008 R2
 •Intel Xeon EM64T 
•AMD Opteron 
 •TCP 
•Named pipes (not supported for LDAP server connections)

Windows XP Professional SP1 or higher
 •Intel Xeon EM64T 
•AMD Opteron 
 •TCP 
•Named pipes (not supported for LDAP server connections)

Windows Vista
 •Intel Xeon EM64T 
•AMD Opteron 
 •TCP 
•Named pipes (not supported for LDAP server connections)

Windows 7 •Intel Xeon EM64T 
•AMD Opteron 
 •TCP 
•Named pipes (not supported for LDAP server connections)

Windows X86 memory requirements are:
•Minimum RAM for Adaptive Server – 80MB
•Minimum RAM per additional user, with default stack size, packet size, and user log cache size – 156KB
•Default user stack size – 41KB
Windows X64 memory requirements are:
•Minimum RAM for Adaptive Server – 127MB
•Minimum RAM per additional user, with default stack size, packet size, and user log cache size – 83KB
•Default user stack size – 73KB
The value of minimum RAM per additional user depends on the connection needs. See the System Administration Guide for information about configuring memory.

Use either of the following patches for both X86 and X64:
•Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package and KB973544
•Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 and KB971090
Windows Disk Space Requirements Product Windows X86 Windows 64 
Adaptive Server typical installation 502MB 500MB 
Default databases created during installation, with Adaptive Server using a 4K page size 306MB 306MB 
Total